# Extracting data from text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file that starts like this:

> ```
> [Details]
> Version=100
> Switch=340
> Video=800
> Date=20100912
> Length=00:49:34.2
> Days=1
> hours=20
> ```

Is there a way that I can check each line within the `[Details]` section and then do something like this?

```
if(line == "version")
{
   // read the int 100
}
```

Also there is other text in the text file that is of no interest to me. I only need to find the `[Details]` part.

Comment: search google for C# File Read loop

Comment: If that file is created by your application - please consider using XML in configuration files. They are little more difficult to handle at the beginning, but later they can save a lot of your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                var keyPair =  sr.ReadLine();
                var key = keyPair.Split('=')[0];
                var value = keyPair.Split('=')[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: That works great, sometimes the code is so little compared to what it can achieve, thank you

Comment: i will accept your answer in 6 mins as it wont let me just yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` to find the lines with `Version`, then parse the `int` from there

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("file").Where(line => line.StartsWith("Version")))
{
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(line.Replace("Version=","").Trim(), out value))
    {
        // do somthing with value
    }
}
```

Or if the file just contains 1 line with Version

```
string version = File.ReadAllLines("file").FirstOrDefault(line => line.StartsWith("Version="));

int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(version.Replace("Version=", "").Trim(), out value))
{
    // do somthing with value
}
```