# How to read the text under it's title from a text file

Tags: c#

I've a text file as below:

[image]

I've learnt [how to read from a text file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b(v=vs.120).aspx). My question: How or is it possible to return the instances (Coke, Juice, Water) under the [Drinks], instead of all text in the file? I would like to apply this idea in my coding so that I can do something like this:

```
string myInput = "Drinks";

if (stringFromtheTxtFile == myInput)
{
  //Print the instances (Coke, Juice, Water) or put them in an array
  //Other actions
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting data from text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213401/extracting-data-from-text-file)

Comment: Use .SkipWhile and .TakeWhile

Comment: Thats a pretty lazy question.  You are supposed to show how you have at least tried to do it yourself first.

Comment: Don't put them in an array, put them in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` ! First do it in a simple loop; only after that think about `LINQ`.. Look into [`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call:

```
 GetListOfEntity("[Drinks]", @"path\sample.txt");
```

static method:

```
    static List<string> GetListOfEntity(string HeaderStringToSearch, string file)
    {
        List<string> retList = File
            .ReadAllLines(file)
            .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith(HeaderStringToSearch))
            .Skip(1)
            .TakeWhile(lines => !lines.Contains(']'))
            .Where(x => x != string.Empty)
            .ToList();

        return retList;
    }
```

Comment: Just for the record I realize that there are duplicate posts and this question does not reflect much research or effort. This is also just to get 'em started as well.

Comment: Hi @FusRoDah, thanks for the solution...if I put my text file to the Resources (e.g. @"Resources\sample.txt"), it wouldn't work, is it because the File class doesn't support for such situation?

Comment: Solved with this: string resource_data = Properties.Resources.sample;